# Remove chars upto specific one in NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c

if i have an NSString eg->

string(102)"?xml etc

How to remove all chars upto and including the double quote. I want to remove the string(102)"

Doing this NSString* newString = [str substringFromIndex:13] works but is not ideal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSRange range = [str rangeOfString:@"\""];
NSString *newString = [str substringFromIndex:range.location + range.length];
```

Is one way.